# Using SQL index on left join

Tags: mysql, sql

A topics table contains 22k topics (not that much). A topics_ignore table for users contains only 33 topics. I am using this SQL query to get the topic count for each user without the ignored topics.

```
SELECT 

COUNT(t.topic_id) AS num_topics

FROM topics t

LEFT JOIN topics_ignore i ON i.topic_id = t.topic_id AND i.user_id = 2

WHERE t.forum_id = 1

AND i.topic_id IS NULL
```

I added already two indexes on the topics table (topic_id, forum_id) and one index on topics_ignore table (topic_id)

The elapsed time is still 0.11015 seconds while other queries are in this range 0.00010s.

How can I benefit from using indexes or how to make this query faster?

Thank you

Comment: 0.1 seconds seems quite fast to me. Is this really a problem? If so, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query), and note that in addition, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: please show output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ....rest of your query`, and show the one that you mention that completes in .0001s along with EXPLAIN output for it, and show output of  `SHOW CREATE TABLE topics` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE topics_ignore`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(t.topic_id) AS num_topics
FROM topics t LEFT JOIN
     topics_ignore i
     ON i.topic_id = t.topic_id AND i.user_id = 2
WHERE t.forum_id = 1 AND i.topic_id IS NULL;
```

You want two indexes:

- `topics(forum_id, topic_id)`
- `topics_ignore(topic_id, user_id)`

The order of the columns in the indexes is important, so the first index is different from the index in your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for getting into. Do you mean I need two indexes over two fields? Like this: CREATE INDEX forum_topic_id ON topics (forum_id, topic_id);

Comment: @LarsVegas . . . Yes.  I fixed the typo in the answer.

Comment: Hello GMB, Hello Gordon Linoff, thank you very much again for getting into my problem and thank you for the investet time. I have compared both of your solutions. At first, both of them are a big improvment. Like I said, the query has needed before you improvement 0.11015s. With the improvement from GMB the query takes only 0.01423s. Great. With the improvement from Gordon the query needs only 0.00943s. I accept the answer from gorden but GMB works also very well.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by rewriting the query with `not exists`:

```
select count(*)
from topics t
where 
    not exists (select 1 from topics_ignore ti where ti.user_id = 2 and ti.topic_id = t.topic_id)
    and t.forum_id = 1
```

Then, you can create the following index, so the subquery executes quickly:

```
topics_ignore(user_id, topic_id)
```

An index on `topics(forum_id, topic_id)` might also help (not that the order of columns is different than in your original code).

That said, your query has a decent execution time already (0.1 sec), and your performance target (0.0001 sec) seems quite unreasonable.

Comment: Thank you very much. the topics_ignore has already an index for the topic_id. Do I have to delete this one and add this one: CREATE INDEX forum_topic_id ON topics_ignore (user_id, topic_id);

Comment: @LarsVegas: technically you don't need to delete the old index, you can just create the new one.

Comment: Thank you and the new one goes over two columns instead of one, correct?

Comment: @LarsVegas: yes, exactly.

Comment: Hello GMB, Hello Gordon Linoff, thank you very much again for getting into my problem and thank you for the investet time. I have compared both of your solutions. At first, both of them are a big improvment. Like I said, the query has needed before you improvement 0.11015s. With the improvement from GMB the query takes only 0.01423s. Great. With the improvement from Gordon the query needs only 0.00943s. I accept the answer from gorden but GMB works also very well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT /*+RESULT_CACHE*/ 

COUNT(t.topic_id) AS num_topics   

FROM topics t

LEFT JOIN topics_ignore i ON i.topic_id = t.topic_id AND i.user_id = 2

WHERE t.forum_id = 1

AND i.topic_id IS NULL
```

Result Cache is a new feature in Oracle 11g and it does exactly what its name implies, it caches the results of queries and puts it into a slice of the shared pool. If you have a query that is executed often and reads data that rarely changes, this feature can increase performance significantly.